# Sorting data with two orderBy() ​does not work (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build an flutter applicationwhic should **order** the **data** I get **from the firestore** by the `date` and by the `time` values given from the firestore. I tried this code, but now the data **doesn't load**, but its loading when I comment one of the two orderBy() out. I use the data afterwards in a StreamBuilder.

This is the code:

```
Firestore.instance
          .collection('customer')
          .document(userUIDglobal)
          .collection('myReservations')
          .orderBy('date')
          .orderBy('time')
          .snapshots(),
```

After getting the data, I display it in a StreamBuilder with this code:

```
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot reservation = snapshot.data.documents[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(reservation['date'].toString()),
              subtitle: Text(reservation['time'].toString()),
            );
          },
        );
```

Here is the code for formatting the date:

```
String formatedDatee = new DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(pickedDate);
```

Here is the code for formatting the time:

```
data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
```

On the screenshot you can see my firestore:

[image]

Here is a screenshot where you can see how the screen lokks when I try runnung the code:

[image]

And this is a screenshot when I comment one of the two `.orderBy()` out:

[image]

**Does anyone know how to solve this problem?**

Comment: Please edit your question to show how you process the data, in a way that shows that it's not ordered. It'd also help to see a screenshot of a document, with its `date` and `time` fields visible.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I edited the question now

Comment: That still doesn't show how you process the data. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it contains lots of advice that increases the chance we can efficiently help you.

Answer (score 1):

Your `date` and `time` fields are stored as string values, in a format that is not useful for sorting. In string sorting, `07.11.2020` is after `06.10.2020`. While you and I may see that these are dates: the database has no idea.

The best solution is usually to store the date/time as a `DateTime` field. Alternatively, you can keep your current fields, but store the values in a format that *does* allow sorting them usefully, e.g. `2020-11-07` and `18:58`. If you sort dates and time strings in these formats, their values are also chronological.

Comment: I tried the secon option mentioned, but it even don't work, I only get the loading symbol of the StreamBuilder , whic is showen when the snapshot has not data

Comment: Is that the same behavior you had before? Also: I'd recommend only showing a loading indicator while you're still loading data. If there's no data, it's better to explicitly show that. Both are separate states in a stream builder.

Comment: Hmm... that seems unexpected. Can you update your question to include the updated code, and a screenshot of the updated documents?

Comment: At first glance that should now work. Can you show where it doesn't work? Either some logging output or a screenshot of the date/time are probably easiest.

Comment: I have now added two screenshots one where you can see my screen when I try runnung the mentioned code and one when I commet one of the two .orderBy() out.